# glTexImage3D undefined reference

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, linker

I have a qmake project in QtCreator running Qt4.8.6 with MinGW.
I include

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

and in my .pro I have

```
QT       += core gui opengl
LIBS     += -L"H:/Programme/Qt/4.8/lib/glew32.lib" -lglew32
LIBS     += -L"H:/Programme/Qt/4.8/lib/OPENGL32.lib" -lopengl32
```

When I build that I get

> error: undefined reference to `_imp____glewTexImage3D'

This is the only function that isn't found, all other openGl functions work just fine. Does someone know how I can use `glTexImage3D()` in Qt4.8? Do I have to build Qt with OpenGL Desktop settings myself?

EDIT: I found prebuilt GLEW libraries for MinGW and with them I dont get the compile error anymore. Instead now the program crushes on execution with no hints of what could be wrong. Any clues?

EDIT2: I made a few changes:

I think some of my path environment variables were wrong, I had the path from a different Qt in there, changed that.

I also dropped the explicit linking of opengl32.lib. It just seemed to me that I wasn't really gonna need it when I was using GLEW.

Third, I put a GLEW dll built for MinGW in the executables directory and it's lib file in Qts lib folder.

IT WORKS! Thanks everyone. If someone could explain, why exactly these steps where necessary, so that we could learn from this post, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: In the previous question I forgot to mention that you have to `#include <GL/glew.h>` before any Qt headers. If you include GLEW headers after Qt, the Qt headers badly interact with the namespace protections of GLEW and you may end up with this problem.

Comment: @Martin Hennig: The crash sounds like GLEW is not properly initialised. Did you properly call `glewInit()` after you got the GL context? And did you make sure it did not return an error code?

Comment: @derhass, there won't be a crash. `Undefined reference` errors are Linker errors and that means only one thing, that there is a static library that has not been linked into the executable.

Comment: @RobbieE: My comment references the part after the EDIT.

Comment: @datenwolf: yes, I include glew.h before anything else. If I tried that, QtCreator would also give me a warning that I shouldn't do this.

Comment: @derhass: I call glewInit(), but since the program wont start, I cannot check any error codes.

Comment: @MartinHennig: Well, if the program crashes, you should be able to run it in a debugger and get some idea about the rough area of the crash. A program might crash before entering `main` (e.g. if soemthing with the libraries or the C runtime itself is screwed up). If it doesn't even run, you will get some more or less helpful error message from the OS. In either case, we need much more information to narrow this down.